# Looping Random Animation Method in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I've been testing a random animation for views inside a view controller. It seems to work well when executed once. However, when I place the code in a while-loop, the application crashes; CPU usage accelerates to 100%. This is due to the constant generation of a random coordinate. What would be the best way to format this code to create a looped random animation, without crashing the app?

```
func randomAnimationForPostPackets () {

func completionMethodX () -> CGFloat {

    let randomCoordinatesXInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)

    let randCoordsX = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesXInt)

    return randCoordsX
}

func completionMethodY () -> CGFloat {


    let randomCoordinatesYInt: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)

    let randCoordsY = CGFloat(randomCoordinatesYInt)

    return randCoordsY

}
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
    self.postPacketView.center.x = completionMethodX()
    self.postPacketView.center.y = completionMethodY()

    },completion:  {(finished:Bool) in

        completionMethodX()
        completionMethodY()
})
}
```

This method is implemented in the viewDidLoad method in the view controller as so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    webBackground()
    createBlurEffectView()
    let randomPositionX : UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randomPositionY : UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(300)
    let randomPositionCGX : CGFloat  = CGFloat(randomPositionX)
    let randomPositionCGY : CGFloat = CGFloat(randomPositionY)

    postPacketView.frame = CGRectMake(randomPositionCGX, randomPositionCGY, 75, 75)
    self.view.addSubview(postPacketView)

    mainSegueButtonSetup()

    **randomAnimationForPostPackets()**

    userViewSetup()

    self.definesPresentationContext = true





    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your `UIView.animateWithDuration` method, you need to have arguments for `options:`.  In this case I believe you would use `.Repeat` and/or `Autoreverse` for your to get your desired effect.

See Apple documentation for `UIViewAnimationOptions` for a complete list of options you can use with your animation.

Edit your code to perform `nil` on `completion:` rather than the two method calls you've listed.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(5, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {
    self.postPacketView.center.x = completionMethodX()
    self.postPacketView.center.y = completionMethodY()

    }, completion: nil
})
```

Comment: Adding the .Repeat and .Autoreverse: 1. Creates an ambiguous reference error. 2. Won't generate new random coordinates.

Comment: 2) It won't generate new random coordinates because you've made some strange nested function declarations. Try getting rid of the two functions completionMethodX and Y and add their code to variables that create new random numbers

Comment: Is your function **randomAnimationForPostPackets()** defined within a UIView class?

Comment: The **randomAnimationForPackets()** function is defined within the viewController within which the views are being rendered.